# Is there a visual list of all Draw.io shapes?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

To my understanding, there is no search feature for Draw.io shapes.

Sometimes, I have to search within Shape categories to find the shape I am looking for or Copy paste icons when the shape already exists in the built-in shapes.

Is there a visual list of all Draw.io shapes?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for shapes via Search field top left but there is no list where all shapes are displayed.